# Put click results of Live Search into a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm performing a live search with my script below and it's working perfectly. The issue is in Chrome when the user clicks on the desired results it gets inserted into a textbox, but it's failing in Firefox.

Secondly, instead of inserting only the text into the textbox, it inserts html tags as well. What I want is the text alone.

```
 $(function() {

     $(".search_tab").keyup(function() {
         var searchid = $(this).val();
         var dataString = 'color=' + searchid;
         if (searchid != '') {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "../search.php",
                 data: dataString,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function(html) {

                     $("#result").html(html).show();
                 }
             });
         }
         return false;
     });

     $("#result").on("click", function(e) {
         var $clicked = $(e.target);
         if (!$clicked.hasClass("search")) {
             $('input.search_tab').val(event.target.innerHTML);
             jQuery("#result").fadeOut();
         }
     });

     $('.search_tab').click(function() {
         jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
     });

 });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`textContent` instead of `innerHTML` like this:

```
$('input.search_tab').val(e.target.textContent);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you accepted this answer, being that it doesn't work. `event` is not defined, so doing `event.target` will throw an error in every browser that isn't Chrome or IE.

Comment: `event` should be `e`. @Santi you could've just said that. Looking at the code he provided I thought the parameter of the callback was `event` and not `e`.

Comment: My point is that your answer at the time had the exact same issue that OP posted this question to resolve, and your answer didn't resolve it, so I'm not quite sure why he accepted it.

Comment: @Santi the original question was about html tags appearing in the text. So the right answer was to use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`. The `event` here was not the original issue so my answer for the issue stated in the question is correct. Plus, in google chrome `event` has a value inside the event listener even if it's not declared anywhere (it's a global variable that gets created when an event is fired). So in GC the code worked and the issue he had was solved and that justify his choice. You could've just edited the answer to fix that side error which wasn't mine by the way.

Comment: I believe the original issue was that it didn't work in Firefox: *The issue is in Chrome when the user clicks on the desired results it gets inserted into a textbox, but it's failing in Firefox.*. But oh well, it's done.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the other answers here. You can't call `event.target` because it will tell you that `event` is undefined, as your event parameter is `e`, not `event`.

Chrome and IE are okay with this because they will provide `event` if it's not defined, though other browsers (like Firefox) will not.

---

You already save the clicked element here:

```
var $clicked = $(e.target);
```

So why store this, only to suddenly switch to `event.target.innerHTML`?

**Do this instead:**

```
 $("#result").on("click", function(e) {
     var $clicked = $(e.target);
     if (!$clicked.hasClass("search")) {
         $('input.search_tab').val($clicked.text());
         $(this).fadeOut();
     }
 });
```

I've fixed the Firefox issue by simply using the `$clicked` variable that you were already using. To grab text only (and not the HTML), I've used jQuery's `.text()`.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/yuztjbva/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method

```
   $('input.search_tab').val($clicked.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change this:

```
success: function(html) {

                 $("#result").html(html).show();
             }
```

to this:

```
            success: function(html) {

                 $("#result").html(html.d).show();
             }
```

And if you want only text:

```
$("#result").html($(html.d).text()).show();
```